# Chrome closing after some time and produce error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/google-chrome")
driver.get('https://python.org')
```

while executing the above code in python, chrome browser opened, but not redirected to https://python.org. After 2 or 3 seconds chrome will automatically close and produce error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 4, in
>   
>       driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/snap/bin/chromium")   File
>   "/home/ShihaD/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
>   line 68, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "/home/ShihaD/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 104, in start
>       raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can
>   not connect to the Service /snap/bin/chromium

I have already tried the solution [Running Selenium WebDriver python bindings in chrome](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/7df9b9) . But not working.

Versions:
Python 2.7.15
Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99
ChromeDriver 2.40

Checked /etc/hosts and 127.0.0.1 localhost is already written there.

Comment: `"/usr/bin/google-chrome"` is a path to `google chrome` web browser, not to a [chrome driver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

Comment: Yep, solved. Thanks!!!